# Can't resolve remote hosts by name over VPN connection, but can access hosts via IP

Tags: windows-10, vpn, dns, pptp, cisco-vpn-client

My small office just acquired a Cisco RV325 VPN router, and I'm setting up a VPN using PPTP. I can connect to the office network using a remote client (Windows 10, built-in), but after I've made the connection, I cannot see the names of hosts on the office network.

I can connect directly to the hosts using their local IP addresses (i.e. "Run" > \192.168.1.x > OK), but that's it. I've tried specifying the office network's DNS IP addresses on the client side, toggling "Use remote gateway" for the connection, etc.

I have a feeling that I need to configure something on my router, but I'm not really sure what it is. Any help would be very appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: You are on the right path with the DNS, you need to use your office DNS are primary resolver. You don't have anything to do on your router because it is unaware of the VPN you are connected to.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I'm very new to solving DNS problems, so I'm not sure how to use the office DNS as the primary resolver. I have a feeling this is something I would configure on the client side... I just don't know how or where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Open the Network and Sharing Centre by right-clicking on your network connections symbol in the bottom-right corner of the screen, then click on Open Network and Sharing Center.

2 - Click on the connection type. (pick your interface)

3 - On the next page, click the Properties button to view your connection properties.

4 - Click once on Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) to highlight it, then click on the Properties button again.

5 - To manually set a DNS server address, make sure to click the radio button next to Use the following DNS server addresses. Next, type in the DNS server address you'd like to use. This can be one you've been given by your Internet Provider, or it could be one of many 'open' DNS servers like Google Public DNS or OpenDNS but in your case you want to use your office DNS in the first field.